# Calling native Java constructors from Frege

Tags: java, jvm, native, frege

Do you know where I can find documentation about Frege's Java bindings? Coming from Haskell, I find that the most interesting aspect of Frege. The [documentation](http://code.google.com/p/frege/downloads/detail?name=Language-609.pdf&can=2&q=) that I found unfortunately does not go into detail very much.

Here is my test example. Basically, I want to translate the following Java code:

```
BigDecimal x = BigDecimal.valueOf(7);
BogDecimal y = new BigDecimal("5.13");
System.out.println(x.add(y));
```

Here is my current Frege code:

```
module Main where

data JBigDecimal s = pure native java.math.BigDecimal
  where
  pure native jAdd add :: JBigDecimal RealWorld -> JBigDecimal RealWorld -> JBigDecimal RealWorld
  pure native jShow toString :: JBigDecimal RealWorld -> String

pure native jBigDecimalI java.math.BigDecimal.valueOf :: Int -> JBigDecimal RealWorld

-- ERROR: Here, I don't know what I should write.
-- I want to bind to the BigDecimal(String) constructor.
-- I tried several versions but none of them was successful, e.g.:
pure native jBigDecimalS java.math.BigDecimal.BigDecimal :: String -> JBigDecimal RealWorld

main :: [String] -> IO ()
main args = let x = jBigDecimalI 7
                y = jBigDecimalS "5.13"
                z = JBigDecimal.jAdd x y
            in printStrLn $ (JBigDecimal.jShow z)
-- (BTW, why `printStrLn` and not `putStrLn` as it is called in Haskell?)
```

Just for completeness, the error message is:

```
calling: javac -cp fregec-3.21.jar:. -d . -encoding UTF-8 ./Main.java 
./Main.java:258: error: cannot find symbol
        return java.math.BigDecimal.BigDecimal(
                               ^
  symbol:   method BigDecimal(String)
  location: class BigDecimal
1 error
E frege-repl/example.fr:15: java compiler errors are most likely caused by
    erronous native definitions
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it. The constructor is called new:

```
pure native jBigDecimalS new :: String -> JBigDecimal RealWorld
```

Comment: Just today I uploaded a new Langspec, with an extended chapter 8. see http://code.google.com/p/frege/downloads/list

Comment: @Ingo Thanks a lot! There it is, section 8.9.4 "Class Instance Creation Expression".

Answer (score 1):

BTW, you don't need the `RealWorld` everywhere. You have a pure native data type, and you apply pure native functions only.

In addition, it turned out that the phantom type convention you use here will not play well when we sometimes support Java Generics. Then we'll have something like

```
data List a = native java.util.LinkedList
```

where we want the `a` with kind `*` map to the generic type parameter. This will not mix well wit state thread indicating phantom types, though.

Therefore (comming soon!) we'll have a type to tag mutable values, it is like

```
abstract data Mutable s a = Mutable a
```

so one can never actually construct/deconstruct a Mutable. This should work so that only native functions can create values of type `Mutable s a` (in the IO or ST monad), and it will then be possible to make a safe copy with `freeze` where one gets a supposedly immutable `a` back. But this one can then not be passed to impure functions that demand a `Mutable  s a`.

But again, as you work with immutable data, just `BigDecimal` is enough (and this is not going to change).

Comment: putStr and putStrLn have been added recently -- see https://github.com/Frege/frege/commit/5bc9f2928cc2bcaed2d86195a9dc58ad6c7fe5e2#frege/Prelude.fr

Comment: Thanks! You are right, the `RealWorld` that I adapted from another example is not necessary here.